# Intrinsics Neon Swap elements in vector

Tags: c++, optimization, arm, simd, neon

I would like to optimize such code with Neon Intrinsics. Basically with given input of

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

will produce the output,

> 2 1 0 5 4 3 8 7 6

```
void func(uint8_t* src, uint8_t* dst, int size){

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
     dst[0] = src[2];
     dst[1] = src[1];
     dst[2] = src[0]
     dst = dst+3;
     src = src+3;
   }           
}
```

The only way I can think of is to use

```
uint8x8x3_t src = vld3_u8(src);
```

to get 3 vectors and then access every single element from src[2], src[1], src[0] and write to the memory.

Can someone please help ?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be fairly straighforward using `VTBL` and `VEXT`  - process 3 x 16 byte vectors at a time, to take care of the different "phase" of each vector.

Comment: Could you share sample code ?

Comment: I don't really have time to write a full solution just now, but look at the ARM documentation for the above two instructions and it should be pretty self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dead easy in the underlying instruction set, because you're swapping two elements of a 3-element structure, which practically spells out the relevant instructions already:

```
vld3.u8 {d0-d2}, [r0]
vswp d0, d2
vst3.u8 {d0-d2}, [r0]
```

There's even this exact example in the [NEON Programmers Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0018a/index.html), because it's a RGB-BGR conversion, and that's exactly the kind of processing NEON was designed for.

With intrinsics it's a bit trickier, as there's no intrinsic for `vswp`; you just have to express it in C and trust the compiler to do the right thing:

```
uint8x8x3_t data = vld3_u8(src);
uint8x8_t tmp = data.val[0];
data.val[0] = data.val[2];
data.val[2] = tmp;
vst3_u8(dest, data);
```

That said, with the compilers to hand being various versions of GCC, I failed to convince any of them to actually emit a `vswp` - code generation ranged from suboptimal to idiotic. Clang did a lot better, but still no `vswp`; other compilers may be cleverer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used "vld3q_u8" instead of "vld3_u8" and the result for the intrinsic seemed to be better, but I implemented it in assembly, but  "vld3.u8 {d0, d2, d4}" only loads 8 elements in each register. Looking at the reference "vld3q_u8" is equivalent to "vld3.8{d0, d2, d4}"

Comment: Doing 16 elements at a time with the `vld3q_u8` intrinsic will actually result in _two_ `vld3.u8` instructions - i.e. `vld3.8{d0, d2, d4} [r0]!; vld3.8{d1, d3, d5}, [r0]` (and consequently two stores at the end, but at least you can still have a single swap using Q registers). That can potentially end up less optimal for some CPUs which prefer loads and stores to alternate as much as possible rather than being bunched up together, but by all means go for whatever's fastest on your machine.