# Swap halves of a NEON vector with C/gcc intrinsics: no intrinsic for VSWP?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm trying to do something relatively simple using NEON vector instructions :
given an `uint64x2_t`, I want to swap position of the 64-bit members.

Aka, if this was a simple normal code :

```
typedef struct {
    U64 u[2];
} u64x2;


u64x2 swap(u64x2 in)
{
    u64x2 out;
    out.u[0] = in.u[1];
    out.u[1] = in.u[0];
    return out;
}
```

Surprisingly enough, I can't find an intrinsic for that. There is apparently an assembler instruction for it ([`VSWP`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDBHEH.html)) but no corresponding intrinsic.

This is weird. It's about as trivial an operation as it can be, so it must be possible. The question is : how ?

*edit* : for reference, `godbolt` outcome using @Jake answer :
https://godbolt.org/z/ueJ6nB .
No `vswp`, but `vext` works great.

Comment: You should mention your compiler. Is it GCC? Or ARMCC?

Comment: Right, currently it is `gcc`

Comment: Here is the citation applicable for [armcc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491i/CIHJBEFE.html): *This instruction has no benefit as an intrinsic because intrinsics use variables to encapsulate register allocation and access. As a result. swapping of variables can be performed using simple C-style variable assignments.*. I guess the same applies to GCC.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.
While it does explain the logic for not providing an intrinsic, it doesn't give a solution, as if this was "trivial". But I don't find that trivial. Do I have to force-cast the `uint64x2_t` into a different type to access its scalar members via a `void*` interface because "hello strict aliasing optimization" ? It seems fragile and overkill. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't have an easy access to neon-enabled compiler to see what is produced from the code you have posted. But I would expect it to detect the pattern and produce code based on VSWP

Comment: @EugeneSh.: ARM GCC on Godbolt has NEON if you use `-mcpu=cortex-a53` or whatever.   https://godbolt.org/.  Or of course it's baseline for arm64.

Comment: Well, looks like this code is not being optimized this way...

Comment: I tried the scalar code on godbolt.org, but could not see any `vswp` instruction. Here is the sample :
https://godbolt.org/z/Fk_Vbd.

ARM64 code doesn't produce any vector instruction. 
I could make armv7 produce neon instruction, using an overly complex compiler directive, but the resulting is very complex and disappointing. We are nowhere near a simple `vswp`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514952/intrinsics-neon-swap-elements-in-vector

Comment: @Cyan: You were just using plain structs which the ABI passes in integer regs, not vectors.  I added a type-pun and a GNU C native-vector attempt (https://godbolt.org/z/EPeMFo), both of which still compile to vec->int->vec.  So still no good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, NEON intrinsics doesn't support the `VSWP` instruction.

However, you can resort to the `VEXT` instruction instead which is also available in intrinsics.

`out = vextq_u64(in, in, 1);`

---

Alternately, you can make use of `vcombine` (and pray that the compiler doesn't mess it up):

`out = vcombine_U64(vget_high_u64(in), vget_low_u64(in));`

But beware, the compilers tend to generate FUBAR machine codes when they see `vcombine` and/or `vget`.

Stay with the former, that's my advice.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, and that's exactly what I did by `VEXT` - swap both halves.

Comment: Thanks @Jake, it works as intended, aka it generates a single `VEXT` instruction instead of `VSWP`. Not sure if `VSWP` would prove faster, but that's likely a very minor difference, and current outcome is already great.

Comment: @Cyan: I wonder the same thing.  `vext` is a byte-granularity sliding window on the concatenation of 2 registers.  It only has 1 `q` output register instead of 2 `d` registers, which might *help*, though.  IDK of any good source that collect ARM instruction timings across microarchitectures the way Agner Fog does for x86, though.  If `vext` has limited throughput but the same latency, then potential bottlenecks would depend on surrounding code and which "ports" / "pipes" / "execution units" they bottlenecked on (if any), at least for an out-of-order CPU.

Comment: @Cyan Don't worry. `VEXT` isn't any slower than `VSWP`, or even better, `VEXT` is considered a permutation instruction, and thus, executes in a different pipeline on Cortex-A8 which makes it potentially faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes There is a "instruction cycle timing" section from ARM. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Cfacfihf.html

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: I've seen that before, but that's specifically for ARM-A8.  I've also seen cycle timings for cortex-m3 or cortex-m in general, but not much where you can just look at one row or column and see "oh, this instruction is slow on some cores but fast on others".  (Agner Fog has a spreadsheet with tabs for each uarch he's tested, so you have to flip around and repeat your search, but that's still pretty useful.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunately, ARM doesn't publish cycle timings after the lackluster Cortex-A9 one which is somewhat understandable considering the many custom cores from Apple, Qualcomm, and Samsung. However, The A8 one is a good basis for building common sense. If you really want to know the exact numbers, you can use the FVP (fixed virtual platform) for Cortex-A9 and A53, and read the cycle counting register. I usually unroll the loop quite deep as far as the register bank allows, and there aren't many cases where I needed the exact numbers bad.

Comment: On x86 there are often multiple ways to do the same thing (e.g. variable-count SIMD bit-shift vs. byte-shuffle vs. integer multiply) or whatever.  Sometimes one strategy is a clear winner after looking at latency, front-end uop cost, and which ports it can run on.  Other times it lets you know that the choice depends on surrounding code.  Like in this case where we wonder about VEXT vs. VSWP as alternate strategies.  I guess with x86 uarches already being set up to relatively efficiently handle multi-uop instructions, there's more scope for some instructions being slower.

Comment: @PeterCordes I ran some complex NEON test codes on both Galaxy Note5(Vanilla Cortex-A57/53) and Galaxy S7(custom Mongoose core), and they do behave differently, the older Note5 generally being faster than the S7. The custom cores are mostly designed for higher power efficiency. Unlike x86/x64 CPUs where only Intel and AMD matter, ARM only licenses the ISA to many vendors who then design custom architectures of their own. And these custom cores are out-of-order ones, and these vendors simply integrate ARM's reference ones such as A53 for the big.LITTLE configuration.

Comment: Yeah, and Apple has their own cores, too.  Stuff like this that causes clock-for-clock differences in execution is exactly why an ARM equivalent of Agner Fog's uarch guides and instruction tables would be so good for getting some kind of handle on some of the major differences between ARM uarches, or the minor differences in instruction performance.  Comparing uarches to each other like Agner Fog does is often helpful for noticing the differences and keeping track of things.

Comment: @PeterCordes That being said, all we really have to know is how ARM's representative in-order core behaves. Codes run fast on Cortex-A53 won't be bad on any custom out-of-order cores. They simply shouldn't be. Always remember that it's more about power efficiency on ARM than pure performance.

Comment: You mean in instruction choice?  With SIMD instructions almost always costing more power, I assume.  Or do you mean in how the cores are designed?  Yes of course performance is a tradeoff vs. power (and die area = dollar cost to manufacture).

Comment: @PeterCordes I've been working on my own "FFTN" (Fastest Fourier Transform on NEON) project that wipes the floor with any open source one such as NE10(which is horrible IMO). On 32bit ARM, it was simply impossible to hide all the latencies due to the limited register number. Then I wrote two `aarch64` versions; To my surprise, the simple port of the 32bit version was faster than the enhanced/extended version where I was able to hide all the latencies thanks to double amount of registers. Loop size DOES matter on ARM.

Comment: @PeterCordes Another example: The Cortex-A15 features a "code buffer"; If the loop consists of less than 16 instructions including the branch instruction at the end, they land into the code buffer where both fetch and decode stage are omitted during its execution which saves a lot of power. I wouldn't be surprised if it ran faster as well. Things got easier since then; I don't unroll the loops that aggressively anymore, and tend to prefer shorter codes. There are many other factors than the cycle counts on ARM due to the power efficiency being the primary concern.

Comment: For some more modern cores (for example Cortex-A76 - https://developer.arm.com/docs/swog307215/latest/arm-cortex-a76-software-optimization-guide) you definitely want to use VEXT (2 cycle latency) rather than VSWP (4 cycle latency). Cortex-A75 would prefer the VSWP to VEXT ( https://static.docs.arm.com/101398/0200/arm_cortex_a75_software_optimization_guide_v2.pdf )

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh Thanks for the links, those might come handy. Still, I wouldn't bother performance in `aarch32` state on any 64bit chip except for the Cortex-A53 maybe. If the vendors are so lame as Samsung (Galaxy A 2016 and Galaxy J 2017 both run 32bit Android on the 64bit Cortex-A53), it's their own fault.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to express this shuffle is with [GNU C native vector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) builtins that give target-independent ways to do a given operation.  Compile-time constant shuffle masks can get optimized into immediate shuffles, according to what the target supports.  But runtime-variable shuffles could be inefficient depending on target ISA support.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

#ifndef __clang__
uint64x2_t swap_GNU_shuffle(uint64x2_t in)
{
    uint64x2_t mask = {1,0};
    uint64x2_t out = __builtin_shuffle (in, mask);
    return out;
}
#endif
```

[AArch64 gcc8.2 on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtQB9T5UgZ1QFdiyTCADkAUgAMAQQIBPAA6YsAMwDU/FjzzAWytQ1RsDR4GoCqANgAs4gMwAhKdOfylqtTwLF%2ByAmvEAdicZNTCLGw1xAFYHACYYgBF7EJdAxI0bAA8Ex2d8mX5suM8AdyYFCCLrHLU8FgBKfODncMyakoECFNbwroA6fhiHSSSAuwz6weHaJJ7Qvv4CadjZ6Iz7SZYVkbm8hbDiTAJBFjUu%2BbTkmXy4u3rkBn4scYBhJmIAW3Y9I36EezYArSfj1AjFdj%2BHjlBTYAAaABUqmCIf56k0bi0DmojidiGcAG6YLIEACO7GqEHqpDqLBptCa%2ByuwNBLHBHUhZQqrwA8gBZBzItmo2kYtKpNq405qAloT4AI3qmApNggBOAx3YCB0CBV1ipjRp6s1hlKeoNDUZqSC1xcNxudweTxe9leXmI9WA/0BzlZ7JynOhFUhikwCk0Qv9cU56OaEvC1VqBE%2BChpyYUFyZbU%2BmE%2ByAUcgg4jilnTNOLlmpnjwAC9MKgVBarb0wumBkNYqN1uMMumdmtklnwm2lv2xps1H2O7t1pcWxoURz/Jn42Ec3mC0WS11yyWRwQado6w2m5dJcdpSvmrbfYuA1CYexMAxczxIyLY5jVwvhUvzksz0WbpO3HCZaRmPYHDCAB6aC1AAcQAOXMNRXjUFgmAIPAiRlTA/BITw5DZJgsnnC5VlArZhi7QdvylfF/26JkbWBYt7hUFgPC4Zg2E4W9f3vLkFHYJDzHYHgEH4FQVBfd8/0/cV5z9EVPiYHgAGsewCYJ6FGdJALCZS/y6LTOHlUEGCwlhxMk6SXzUA0aVUjTm2xeizivTEbzuTBOLwFRRAaRgxGiURSBYMRJDC1AxDQvhBGEAI7loMKCEiwKgvUkA7DsfocusQJaDiAAOOIissQJrFoSxgtEawwoi0QotIGLRDCngQEkUg0qawLSDgWAkDlBQ8BfMgKAgYbRswYgUA%2BT4bGAUqupUUaCBmjqIE4dhJEoIL5XS0hFQw4g5DEFLSDlHM2R5FgGDO3rSCwVS2BfQ78COPxsMwDrHuJPClhEUQLrBZ9DqoUl%2BBmh7crifoLpfNgCCQegGDweViA%2BORXgwIGLoUI4CR5eUqDwtKts4XaICPGsX1oaJJEkKrAmiWhaEkABOaxKE0VQlXQSgXw1Tj4GiUguuBjLLUYXzgGRuhSAJzAiZJsnKG2qmqAARSh067DKyQ4g5hnio543StoQI4kq2g7FoSh8B4BRmAevqabphmmct1n2a5nnOMwVa9AFiAhd8gXIDFiWUstaXEbllHpe8PBPnOvqeI4LhGHRjrICC1AFCwoxfoAWh5Ow1BLjchgmNBiHWrIS6YaJAnagQhBEBlatC8LDta6QACU%2BUiYBkGQNRiv6EoIFwQgCLY%2BhUNQFNpuIJK7YaVDUvSoKICG5eRrG8hKCmsa5q%2BJa4hWtaNvVym9qOw7jqxtPLuX66CFu%2B73tzVhgDex6H0ybfV%2Bs1f6yBAav1BgwcGkNoZiFhvDMK8d5ao3RpjU6OMsCvyVirUmfg747UoO7TA9NGbMx9pzbmVQA5B2UILTAwsI4QCjqQSWscgooJRorQmxN8Hkw1pQbWus5D63ZkbE2ZtogWytjbO2Ds8BOxdmIN2tZaakM9hQtmVD/Z82DgwphotxZsJjrHGWSNE5BWTqndhjA/4gG2twNG8pc4QHzoXPAxcxBlwrlXFQ4ZNi/BYCXAk/iCTWErp8GSqBMJN0VJsPgKgCD%2BMifNSJ%2BYa6JDrg3JuLc24JU7pwkKDU%2B5iEHnyNQo9x6T2nrPIga8F40hxivMa687Cb1eNvXq0sso5TynbY2dhirWGiHYM2cRohixgXVMKqd2ZdUas1Vq7VOrdR3v1GAiAUAH1XsfSaOyz5jwzsVRmpBVqWVvhTIhbjH6PWfqdV%2BV1fKfzug9Zqz0/4APeXgT6WEiSgLCuAyBktyBsjBo9CGIiEFTyQeYhOCtnEYOxrjHBvDVYEKuVTEhZCvYs20X7Ghej6Gh0YeHIx0cpacNlqgnhys%2BFq0xUInW0MxGG2NpIU25syqyKqvIiAjtnZMFdkFbFmjvb4uobzQO/MDFksjsY9hZiuF0CTh6GxMc7FsAcVnZxrj3FFy0N48ulcCAfA1P4eaNh8kdxVd3Epj1WpZGKpYEukRHh/wnv0SQXqHJ1PnslJpByZrrziB0rpUUenZVyjlGNsa421Xqr3B1KjeCrJ6hGopog4j2qWSm9NGVSBEmINoIwIBrBAA%3D%3D) does actually compile to the same shuffle Jake suggested, not SWP:

```
swap_GNU_shuffle:
        ext     v0.16b, v0.16b, v0.16b, #8
        ret
```

Clang also optimizes most of our pure-C attempts to an `ext` instruction, including one that uses `memcpy` to type-pun to your plain struct and back.  Unlike GCC, which doesn't have as good a shuffle optimizer.  (On Godbolt, use any `clang` from the dropdown with `-O3 -target arm64`.  clang is normally built with support for multiple target ISAs by default, unlike GCC.)

So either all of these compilers have missed optimizations for tune=generic and `-mcpu=cortex-a53`, `a57`, and `a75`, or else `ext` is actually a good choice, perhaps better than `swp` which has to write 2 output registers instead of logically writing one full-width register.  But usually that's not a problem for ARM; quite a few instructions can do that and they usually make it efficient.

[ARM's timing info for Cortex-A8](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/ch16s06s06.html) has the same numbers for `vext` and `vswp` (both are 1 cycle latency from `Qn` to `Q`output, but 2 cycles from `Qm` to `Q`output).  I haven't checked newer cores (or any 64-bit cores).